# Kusto ANY / ALL operators (larger than column)

Tags: mysql, sql, azure, azure-data-explorer, kql

I have a query like the following ([data taken from tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/ingest-sample-data))

```
SELECT State, EventType, DamageProperty From StormEvents where DamageProperty >= ALL(select DamageProperty from StormEvents where State = 'NEW YORK') AND EventType = 'Wildfire'
```

I want to translate this query to KQL, but I'm having trouble with translating the ALL operator.

The following query would receive the same results:

```
StormEvents | where (DamageProperty >= toscalar( StormEvents | where State == "NEW YORK" | summarize max(DamageProperty) ) and EventType == "Wildfire") | distinct State, EventType, DamageProperty | limit 1000
```

But I don't want to use `max()`, I want for future use know how to use the any / all operators (and somehow I didn't find something related on Google).

Answer (score 1):

I don't know Kusto.  But the following SQL is equivalent:

```
select se.State, se.EventType, se.DamageProperty
from StormEvents se
where se.DamageProperty >= (select max(se2.DamageProperty)
                            from StormEvents se2
                            where se2.State = 'NEW YORK'
                           ) and
      se.EventType = 'Wildfire';
```

I also find it odd that you are filtering on the event type only in the outer query.  I would expect the same filter in the subquery as well.

Note:  There is a difference between this version and your query, if there are no matching rows in the subquery.  You can handle this with a slight tweak:

```
where se.DamageProperty >= (select coalesce(max(se2.DamageProperty), se.DamageProperty)
                            from . . .
```

Comment: Thanks! Your comment helped. But I'll accept my answer since there isn't an actual direct translation from ANY / ALL.

Comment: @sheldonzy . . . The last option is a direct translation.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out there isn't a direct translation to ANY / ALL.

The answer I received from Microsoft support:

> We have looked upon your request and unfortunately we could not find a
>   way to translate the ANY/ALL operators in a Kusto stream at this
>   moment. We will keep searching for a workaround but we recommend you
>   to try looking for alternatives.